Older Movie Mansion + Booby trapped rooms
I saw a movie about 10 years ago.  I saw it on a french channel (but
it could have been dubbed into French).  These are the things that I
remember from the movie, but I would like to know the name of the
movie.  There is a man and a lady who are exploring a bunch of rooms
in search for a briefcase full of money.  The rooms are all booby
trapped and dark, and it seems like they're in catacombs.  The
mastermind behind the briefcase of money is a bedridden old man.  I
think he lives in a very very large mansion.  The booby-trapped
rooms/catacombs might be underground in this mansion.  These are all
the facts that I remember.  The name of the movie was something like
The Seven Rooms, or the Five Rooms.  Or chambers... there was a number
somewhere in the title I believe.  Help me find this movie please.

You are the greatest!  This is it!!  Brilliant!  Thank you!!!
